# Django migration not working properly on Heroku

Tags: python, django, bash, heroku

I have deployed a Django App like 3 months ago and i was able to migrate changes easily on the heroku bash. Right now i'm trying this:

```sh
heroku run python manage.py migrate
```

Also tried this:

```sh
heroku run python manage.py migrate --no-input
```

And i tried accesing to the heroku bash like this:

```sh
heroku run bash
```

And then run:

```sh
~ $ python manage.py migrate
```

All this commands seems to work:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWW6S.png

But they don't. When i tried to migrate again, i thought it would show me the typical ***No migrations to apply.***. But this is not the case

¿What should i do to migrate changes?

Comment: What database are you using? Sqlite?

Comment: @MarcusAldrey Yes

Comment: Could you please share some more details, what are you able to see on the console, do you able to see the data / tables in the DB. when you run your application do you able to see new migrated tables or not ?
did you try to run the same migration locally ?
Django version on heroku vs local ?

Comment: @ShreeyanshJain I tried to type ```python manage.py shell``` so i can see if the tables where added, but they don't. I think it is becouse of what @MarcusAldrey said in the answers. Heroku remove inmediately the migration changes. And yes, i deployed the app on pythonanywhere and it works perfectly. The problem is only on Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQlite, the migration changes on Heroku are applied and removed immediately. You have to use Heroku Postgres add-on (check on the your project overview if it's already installed) and add this to your settings.py

```
if "DATABASE_URL" in os.environ:
    import dj_database_url

    DATABASES = {"default": dj_database_url.config()}
```

you can also add this to your Procfile to migrate on deploy

```
release: python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: I already added the **release** in the **Procfile**. I want to test that change on **settings.py** but i'm using pythonanywhere and there, this django app works as expected. It may change the behavior and i only want to use heroku to test things and pythonanywhere for production deployment.